# reducing array based on duplicates

Tags: arrays, duplicates, extendscript

I am trying to remove duplicates from an indesign array using extendscript

my array example is

file_one 1
file_two 1
file_one 1
file_two 1
file_one 1
file_two 1

I am trying to merge to get

file_one 3
file_two 3

any idea's

thanks!!!!

sample of script below

```
    for (var j = i; j < ra.length; j++){
        if (ra[j].cells[0].contents == fn) {
            cnt = cnt + Number(ra[j].cells[col].contents)
            nn ++
            if (nn > 1) {
                ra[i].cells[col].contents = cnt.toString()
                dupes.push(ra[j])
            }
        } 
    }; 
};
var n = dupes.length;
while (n--) dupes[n].remove();
```

when I try to remove the duplicates I get an empty array

any idea's

thanks!!!!

Comment: It's not clear what the original array looks like. Right now it looks like a string with names and numbers. It's not an array. And the same trouble with output, it's not an array either. An array looks like this: `['file_one', 'file_two', 'file_one', 'file_two', 'file_one', 'file_two']` or `['file_one 1', 'file_two 1', 'file_one 1', 'file_two 1', 'file_one 1', 'file_two 1']` or `['file_one', '1', 'file_two', '1', 'file_one', '1', 'file_two',  '1', 'file_one', '1', 'file_two']`, etc. Each of these cases has its own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solition:

```js
var arr = ['file_one', 'file_two', 'file_one', 'file_two', 'file_one', 'file_two'];
var obj = {};

while (arr.length) {
  var key = arr.pop();
  if (key in obj) obj[key] += 1; else obj[key] = 1;
}

var output = [];
for (key in obj) output.push(key + ' ' + obj[key]);

console.log(output); // ['file_two 3', 'file_one 3']
```

But from your description and your code it's not clear what exactly you have and what exactly you want to get.

Your 'array' is not an array. It looks like a string.

An array looks like this:

`['file_one', 'file_two', 'file_one', 'file_two', 'file_one', 'file_two']`

or

`['file_one 1', 'file_two 1', 'file_one 1', 'file_two 1', 'file_one 1', 'file_two 1']`

or

`['file_one', 1, 'file_two', 1, 'file_one', 1, 'file_two', 1, 'file_one', 1, 'file_two', 1]`

...etc

Each of these cases has its own solution.

Comment: That data could also be an Object like `{file_one: 1, file_two: 1, …}`